# SQL LocalDB - Cannot delete a DB when its files are deleted

Tags: ssms, localdb

How can I delete a SQL LocalDB database that has had its files delete?

Dropping the database yields this message:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Public\Documents\LocalDB.Tests.3d0d7339-7cf2-45fe-a83b-b5079112ab80.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
>
> File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Users\Public\Documents\LocalDB.Tests.3d0d7339-7cf2-45fe-a83b-b5079112ab80_log.ldf" may be incorrect.

Running `master.sp_databases` actually doesn't show them, but the Management Studio does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find file specified when dropping LocalDb database if .mdf was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228400/cannot-find-file-specified-when-dropping-localdb-database-if-mdf-was-deleted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using (localdb) bundled with SQL Server 2012.

*If you're using SQL Server 2014, **use (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** in place of **(localdb)\v11.0** below*

- Open a command prompt
- Start the localDb instance if it is not already running: `“C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqllocaldb.exe” start “v11.0″`
- Drop the localDb database by running the following command: `“C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd” -S (localdb)\v11.0 -E -d master -Q “DROP DATABASE [myDatabase]”`
- You can stop the localDb service now: `“C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqllocaldb.exe” stop “v11.0″`

*Source: http://kazimnami.azurewebsites.net/techblog/2013/02/27/delete-localdb-database-after-physical-files-have-been-deleted/*

Comment: It still gives an error, though after refresh, the DB nodes are now gone from SSMS.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are trying to drop a database when the physical file has been deleted or couldn't be found.

To get around this you can detach the database. Detaching will drop the database without attempting to remove the file from the filesystem.

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'My_Db'
```

Comment: I got it fixed in another way before I managed to see your comment, but I'm sure other users will benefit from your link, thank you so much!