# Cannot find file specified when dropping LocalDb database if .mdf was deleted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, localdb

I am trying to write an application that will create a local database if it's not found in the application's folder. I run this query after deleting the .mdf

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'Test_db')
BEGIN 
     DROP DATABASE Test_db 
END

CREATE DATABASE Test_db 
ON PRIMARY (NAME=Test_db, FILENAME='...\Test_db.mdf')
```

My `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` throws an exception, even though it drops the database and creates a new one. The error comes from the `DROP DATABASE` part of the command.

> Additional information: Unable to open the physical file
>   "...\Test_db.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2 (The system cannot
>   find the file specified.)".
>
> File activation failure. The physical file name
>   "...\Test_db_log.ldf" may be incorrect.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905318/sql-localdb-cannot-delete-a-db-when-its-files-are-deleted) question, but it has no solution to the problem.

Comment: Is it `...` in the path to `mdf` file actual code, or this is an example? The path you try to write this file is accessible from your app? I just check your code with this path: `d:\Test_db.mdf` and it is perfectly working

Comment: @gofr1 The ...\ is an example. I use a method to build the path using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and I just replaced the values to make it easier to read. But as stated, the .mdf is created just fine, it's just dropping the database that throws the error because I deleted the .mdf.

Comment: Then why you delete file if DROP should do this?

Comment: @gofr1 I'm trying to handle a case where the `.mdf` was deleted. I cannot just create the database, because it already exists, and dropping it throws the error.

Comment: As I know if `mdf` file is deleted, but DB is not dropped (for example this occasionally had happened) then it (by default) goes into `RECOVERY_PENDING` mode. You can check it in `sys.databases` table in `state_desc`

Comment: @gofr1 Your comment had me doing some more research which eventually led to me to, what seems like, an obvious answer. Check out the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to `sp_detach_db` because it removes the database from the server without deleting files from the file system

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'Test_db'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the file being deleted, try [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (File.Exists(pathname))
{
    // Execute your SQL
}
else
{
    // Error processing
}
```

Comment: I make this check, but I execute the SQL if it doesn't exist so it will create a .mdf. In other words, the SQL is the error processing and nothing needs to be done if the database file exists